# configure: error: cannot find java include files

Tags: java, file, include, configure, mapserver

I'm trying to install MapServer on my Linux CentOS 5.9 server but keep getting the same error.

```
checking if --with-java-include-os-name specified... no, autodetected linux
checking for javac... /usr/bin/javac
checking symlink for /usr/bin/javac... /etc/alternatives/javac
checking symlink for /etc/alternatives/javac... /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj/bin/javac
checking symlink for /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj/bin/javac... /usr/bin/ecj
configure: error: cannot find java include files
```

I read somewhere else that this could be fixed by installing sun-jdk packages instead of gjc. Now, the thing is is I don't have root access on my work computer currently. So I tried downloading the jdk files onto my desktop and configuring using

```
./configure --with-java-include-os-name=~/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_21
```

but still got the same error.

```
checking if --with-java-include-os-name specified... yes (~/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_21)
checking for javac... /usr/bin/javac
checking symlink for /usr/bin/javac... /etc/alternatives/javac
checking symlink for /etc/alternatives/javac... /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj/bin/javac
checking symlink for /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj/bin/javac... /usr/bin/ecj
configure: error: cannot find java include files
```

I'm not really sure I'm using that command right. But my main question is how do I fix this error without root access? Is that possible? Do I need to ask for the root password to install sun-jdk? And if I did that how do I change where the configure file will look for the include files it needs so that it stops looking in the gcj files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Macports version of Mapserver. They are still on version 6.2.1, which is one the last versions not to use CMake. As of version 6.4, Mapserver is using CMake.

To get around the issue, you need to edit `configure` script. Search for string "cannot find java include files" and just comment out the line which halts the execution when java include files are not found.

This isn't a fix, but just a dirty workaround to get you through a bug in configuration process. This should give you a fully working build.